# How to query Instance details within an Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using AWS CLI for example:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name $1 --region us-east-1
```

We can get JSON data as ouput which includes many attributes.
I want only Instances attribute in my output like

```
Instances": [
            {
                "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
                "LaunchConfigurationName": "ASG name",
                "LifecycleState": "InService",
                "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
                "InstanceId": "i-abced",
                "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
            },
            {
                "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
                "LaunchConfigurationName": "ASG name",
                "LifecycleState": "InService",
                "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
                "InstanceId": "i-abced",
                "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
            }
        ]
```

Do we have any CLI command for this or else how can we query the output of

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name $1 --region us-east-1
```

for "Instances" attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output using [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).

```
 aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name my-auto-scaling --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].Instances[*]" --output json
```

output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-1234567abcd",
            "InstanceType": "t3a.micro",
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
            "LifecycleState": "InService",
            "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
            "LaunchConfigurationName": "abc",
            "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-12345abc",
            "InstanceType": "t3a.micro",
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2b",
            "LifecycleState": "InService",
            "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
            "LaunchConfigurationName": "abc",
            "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks  Adiii, yes it worked .. just added region

"aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name $1 --region us-east-1 --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].Instances[*]" --output json"